# Commerce payment for Rooms reserveration only after the order is confirmed

Tags: commerce, bookings

I want to use [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) + [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) and wonder if there’s a configuration/module for the following procedure:

1. User reserves a room, checks out, but isn’t allowed to pay yet.
2. The room owner gets an email and confirms/declines the order.
3. If confirmed, the user gets an email and can now start the payment process in the checkout.

Rooms offers an "[enquiry mode](https://www.drupal.org/node/1947284)" (instead of the mode for booking directly), but as far as I understand it, this only sends an email (no order is created), so this enquiry never reaches Commerce.

Comment: Not familiar with the Rooms module, does it integrate with Rules?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the [Easy Booking](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_booking) distribution, to check if there is anything in it similar to what you're looking for (specific to the way this distribution uses [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)). If you find something, it is just a matter of reusing what's appropriate in your own site.

Here are some more details about this distribution (quotes from its project page):

> ... to set up a website, that will suit all your needs in managing your own hotel, inn or hostel online.
>
> It gives a set of options for visitors to make room reservations, contact hotel administration or just follow hotel’s newsletter to be aware of all special offers and discounts.
> Easy booking profile is powered by Drupal [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) - widely used and popular contributed decisions, which means active maintaining and timely technical support.